# How to complete a scheduled coroutine task without exiting the main coroutine in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

So i have a main coroutine object in python which is a "run forever" event loop, i am scheduling a task to run another "run forever event loop" until the user requests to cancel it. then go back to the main event loop. In theory i want to run a task indefinitely until i want to stop it and call it whenever i want.

To give a better detail:

1. MAIN EVENT ---> SCHEDULED EVENT
2. SUSPEND MAIN EVENT
3. SCHEDULED EVENT ---> MAIN EVENT
4. EXIT/SUSPEND SCHEDULED EVENT

---

forgive my lack of understanding if any, as i am still a novice in asyncio modules and coding itself

I tried running the main event loop and use it to schedule a task, this task runs forever so i made a condition which would make an attempt to go back to the main coroutine. i am successful in resuming the main coroutine but i am unable to suspend or stop the scheduled task. i tried using "task.cancel" , return statements, "asyncio.wait()", etc. i am also using an event decorator within the coroutine.

I apologize again for my lack of understanding in this area if any. please let me know what i should be doing or what i am trying is impossible

Comment: You can call the scheduled event from the main event, and once the scheduled event is done, the asyncio loop will return back to the main event. It sounds like you are overthinking the problem, or perhaps have a gap of knowledge on how asyncio works.

Comment: If you can add some stub code, with the structure you are thinking about, even if each forever co-routine will just use `await asyncio.sleep(...)` and some prints, it will be possible to come out with a nice answer for you.

Comment: @sync I think for now just creating an imaginary situation to reflect my problem doesn't seem to help much. i will create a new thread which will define my problem specifically. Thank you for your support. i will also be deleting this thread as it wont help much

Comment: I believe you answered the wrong person. Whatever the case, @jsbueno is right. Creating an example is not for _your_ sake (though sometimes it might help you realize your mistake/problem), but for the sake of others trying to understand & help you. See [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).